# Autofac Single Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have the following problem understanding how the singleinstance binding works

I have the following class listing

```
public interface ICacheManager
{
    object Get(string key);

    void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime);

    bool IsSet(string key);

    void Invalidate(string key);
}
```

Implemented as follows

```
public class MemoryCacheManager : ICacheManager
{
    private ObjectCache Cache
    {
        get { return MemoryCache.Default; }
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        return Cache[key];
    }

    public void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
    {

        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime) };
        Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
    }

    public bool IsSet(string key)
    {
        return Cache[key] != null;
    }

    public void Invalidate(string key)
    {
        Cache.Remove(key);
    }

}
```

Registered in autofac as follows

```
 builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().SingleInstance();
```

Now my question is this

say i have the following class listing that uses the ICacheManager dependency

```
public class ClassA
{
    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
    public ClassA(ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
      _cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

   private void BindItem(object o)
   {
     if(!_cacheManager.IsSet("SOME_KEY"))
         _cacheManager.Set("SOME_KEY", O, 60);
   }
}
```

After the Object O has been added to the Cache, if the ICacheManager instance is resolved at a latter time, will it contain the newly added item or not.

Comment: In your case it doesn't even matter how you register the `MemoryCacheManager`, since it contains no state. It simply redirects to `MemoryCache.Default` and whether or not that will contain the newly added item is up to the `MemoryCache.Default` implementation.

Comment: @Steven Pardon my naivety, I should have known it wont make any difference. Just went through the docs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When an object is registered `SingleInstance` the exact same instance that was returned at the first request for that object will be returned for every other request for an instance of that object. So, to directly answer your question, yes. If you resolve `ICacheManager` from the container, add an instance to the cache, and then later request an `ICacheManager` instance, the second request will receive the exact same instance of the cache manager as the first request and barring your cached item having been ejected from the cache, your item would be present in the cache.

You can verify this behavior using unit tests:

```
// NUnit test fixture - untested, please forgive any typos
[TestFixture]
public class AutofacComprehensionTest
{
    internal interface ICacheManager {}
    internal class ConcreteCacheManager : ICacheManager {}

    [Test]
    public void SingleInstance_causes_same_instance_to_be_returned_for_each_request()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ConcreteCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().SingleInstance();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var first = container.Resolve<ICacheManager>();
        var second = container.Resolve<ICacheManager>();
        Assert.That(first, Is.SameAs(second));
    }
}
```

Comment: What if we call Resolve<ICacheManager> from a different instance of ContainerBuilder?